# Return an XML formatted result from Web service Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have this simple formatter class in my webservice

```
public class SimpleFormatter extends BaseFormatter
{

    public String getXml(String str)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(XML);
        sb.append(str);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getXml(byte[] ba)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(XML);
        sb.append(new String(ba));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
        String result = sf.getXml("<result></result>");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

**BaseFormatter Class**

```
 public abstract class BaseFormatter
{

    protected static final String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>";
    protected static final String ERROR = "error";
    protected static final String RESULT = "result";

    public static final String EMPTY = XML + "<results/>";

    protected StringBuilder sb = null;  

    protected void openTag(String tag)
    {
        sb.append("<");
        sb.append(tag);
        sb.append(">");
    }

    protected void openTagWithAttr(String tag, String attr, String val)
    {
        sb.append("<");
        sb.append(tag);
        if (val.length()>0)
        {
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(attr);
            sb.append("=\"");
            sb.append(val);
            sb.append("\"");
        }
        sb.append(">");
    }

    protected void closeTag(String tag)
    {
        sb.append("</");
        sb.append(tag);
        sb.append(">");
    }

/**
Returns an error document
**/

    public String getError(String msg)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(XML);
        openTag(ERROR);
        sb.append(msg);
        closeTag(ERROR);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void addEmpty(String tag)
    {
        sb.append("<");
        sb.append(tag);
        sb.append("/>");
    }

/**
Adds elements to the document; NOTE: adds an empty element even if the value list is empty
**/

    protected void addElement(List<String> vals, List<String> keys)
    {
        int len = vals.size();
        openTag(RESULT);
        if (len == 0 && keys.size() > 0) addEmpty(keys.get(0));
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
        {
            String key = keys.get(i);
            openTag(key);
            sb.append(vals.get(i));
            closeTag(key);
        }
        closeTag(RESULT);
    }
```

}
And im using it to format result when using the web service

```
 private SimpleFormatter formatter = null;


      public String getJobData(Map<String, String> paramMap)
  {
    String str1 = (String)paramMap.get("jobId");
    if (str1 == null) {
      return this.formatter.getError("No job ID provided for query");
    }
    Query_filter localQuery_filter = new Query_filter("Job", str1);
    Query_filter[] arrayOfQuery_filter = { localQuery_filter };
    Node localNode = mgr.getQueryResult("HolderJob", JOB_NAMES, JOB_TAGS, arrayOfQuery_filter);
    if (localNode == null) {
      return this.formatter.getError("Could not retrieve job data; check job ID");
    }
    String str2 = null;
    try
    {
      str2 = Documents.writeToString(localNode);
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {}
    return this.formatter.getXml(str2);
  }
```

I am getting a null pointer exception when using the formatter  class.

but if i do it like this:

```
return str2;
```

the result im getting is just a plain string:

**false150305510190 ROW VERI219254591150110**

This is the result i am expecting if i use the formatter class.

```
<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>150305</MinorRev><Operation>510190 ROW VERI</Operation><Experiment>219254</Experiment><HTNum>591</HTNum><WaferEC>150110</WaferEC></Table>
```

Im using Netbeans 8.0.2

Apache 7.0.63

Can anyone guide me about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you debug, e.g. why you get the NPE etc.? Did you check the _exact_ content of `str2` before it is returned? Does it contain XML tags?

Comment: I also don't see how your formatter would be expected to do anything other than concatenate two strings so it might just not do what you want. In general be as specific with your questions as possible, do your homework first (e.g. debugging) and then ask a question that shows the effort you put into it. That way people will be more likely to be willing or able to help.